# SQL Server - High buffer time

Tags: sql-server, time, buffer, wait

[image][image]

I'm noticing a high number of waitingRequestsCount on SQL server. The latch_class is buffer. See attached screenshots. Going through SQL server dashboard, I see high number (32221334) waits for Buffer Pool. Can someone please explain what could contribute to high number of waits?

Comment: I propose to shift this thread to https://dba.stackexchange.com for better answer.

Comment: I think you start investigating by finding query which use parallelism.Parallelism is both Boon and bane.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone please explain what could contribute to high number of waits?

Those are latch waits, required to maintain the integrity of a page in memory when it needs to be accessed by multiple sessions.  A high *number* of latch waits is not a cause for concern.  If the wait time is significant, it might indicate a problem that needs further [troubleshooting](https://download.microsoft.com/download/B/9/E/B9EDF2CD-1DBF-4954-B81E-82522880A2DC/SQLServerLatchContention.pdf).   Even though you have a high *number* of latch waits, they are on average pretty short, and these statistics are cumulative since the last time the SQL Server instance started.

Instead diving into the Latches, start with the Waits, which provide a much more holistic view of workload performance (although event this view is missing the total CPU time to put the waits in context).

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I see a high number of CPU Parallelism waits. See updated screenshit

Comment: The parallelism waits aren't necessarily a problem.  They simply indicate that there are a lot of parallel query plans running, where some threads in the plan are waiting on other threads to complete.

Comment: I've noticed that the same job runs in few minutes to few hours. I am trying to identify what could cause a specific job to have such a varied time. Based on screenshot, can you point me to where to look for to identify the root-cause